# I need to customize the deployment of wordpress with my own set of rules and control

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am a WordPress/ Web designer. I need to speed up production for my clients I have been doing everything manually for some time now installing plugins etc. I want to create a WordPress image that has all of the plugins I want to have already installed and the restrictions want. So I don't have to continue. To do the same thing over an over.

For Example, When the client logins for the first time they have to change the password and they are only restricted to a certain things

Comment: Kindly but you should hire someone if you don't know how to do it yourself, as StackOverFlow is not a free coding service. We just help people on provided code issues.

Comment: So can it  be done

Comment: What you are asking is just too vague… Everything is possible depending on your skills, the time to be spent and of course the budget. StackOverFlow is related to coding on real provided code, so not the place for this type of questions.

Comment: ok thank you for your input